# AWS S3 error with MySQL dump importation in Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-s3, dump

I'm getting this error:

> Aws\Common\Exception\InstanceProfileCredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" options when creating a client or provide an instantiated Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object. ([curl] 28: Connection timed out after 5010 milliseconds [url] http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/) in Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient->getInstanceProfileCredentials() (line 85 of /var/www/public/sites/all/libraries/awssdk2/Aws/Common/InstanceMetadata/InstanceMetadataClient.php).

In this scenario:

I'm using the AWS S3 module in Drupal 7. One bucket from S3 works for development, and the other one works for staging.

After the client add some content in staging, I try to import the new DB dump from staging to develop and the error appers, maybe is something with the image path in the new dump, the AWS credentials work for development fine, the problem is with the new DB dump.

Con someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your instance is not able to authenticate to S3 bucket specified.

1) Set AWS Credentials in your Environment Path ( Not Recommended ). Instead you shoud assign AWS IAM Role to the Instance to give access to S3 resource.

2) You need to change S3 bucket permission such that it allows the present server to access the bucket.

Iam not sure if this is your real case. Please elaborate your question so that we can give a precise solution.
I'm not allowed to comment. so, had to post an answer.